# Layout format of table in html using jstl

Tags: html, html-table, jstl

I have created some methods in bean which are called in jsp page.I have three method namely refernece_vacc1,refernece_vacc2 and diff out of whcih the first two return list and third one return map.All the three method return correct value.I want to display all the return values in tabular format such as-

```
Label_name   Reference  To-be-Compared  Difference
Beam_Energy  5.5567     0.0             5.5567
bag1_rb      6.6        6.6             0.0
```

I want the layout such that first row return by all method should be in one row,second row of all methods should be in second row respectively.I'm not getting expected output.I tried as-

```
 <table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2" style="border: solid;">

<tr>
<tH>Bag_Name</tH>
<th>Reference</th>
<th>To be Compared</th>
<th>Difference</th>
</tr>

<tr><td>beam_energy</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag1_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag2_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag3_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag4_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag5_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag6_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag7_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag8_rb</td></tr>
<tr><td>bag9_rb</td></tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refernece_vacc1(40.00)}">
<c:forEach var="rw" items="${ref.refernece_vacc2(40.00)}">
<c:forEach var="d" items="${ref.diff()}">
<tr><td><c:out value="${rw}"></c:out>  </td>
<td>
<c:out value="${row}"> </c:out>  </td>
<c:out value="${row}"> </c:out> 
<c:forEach var="cl" items="${d.value}" >
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${cl==0}">
<td bgcolor="green">${cl}</td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<td bgcolor="red">${cl} </td></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach></tr>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```